# Tkinter can't assign the image

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
add-button-image = tk.PhotoImage(file = "Add-Button.png")
```

I use tkinter in a py program so I can add an image on a button. the png file I want to add is in the same path as the python program.
Every time I run the program I get an error "can't assign to operator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use dashes use underscore.

```
    add_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="Add-Button.png")
```

Comment: Thank you, that help us with more attributes